# SQL missing operator error

Tags: sql, excel, odbc

What is wrong with the below line of SQL

Relevant line:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM glossary.csv 
 WHERE source NOT IN ('AIS','AIP','ICAO','WATOG','ICAO/AIP') 
  AND NOT LIKE('CASR%')"
```

Error:

```
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80040e14'

[Microsoft][ODBC Text Driver] Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'source NOT IN ('AIS','AIP','ICAO','WATOG','ICAO/AIP') AND NOT LIKE('CASR%')'.

/junk/glossary.asp, line 20
```

Comment: Missing "source" or other column value before "not like('CASR5')  Should be 






"SELECT * FROM glossary.csv WHERE source NOT IN ('AIS','AIP','ICAO','WATOG','ICAO/AIP') AND source NOT LIKE('CASR%')"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You missed out the column name in the second part of the where clause:

```
"SELECT * FROM glossary.csv 
 WHERE source NOT IN ('AIS','AIP','ICAO','WATOG','ICAO/AIP') 
 AND source  NOT LIKE 'CASR%'"
```